# Mautic Mail Send Settings cannot work after Monitored Inbox Settings is done

Tags: email, send, mautic

If I remove the Monitored Inbox Settings, then Mail send Settings is no problem.
After it is set like attached photos,the Mail Send Settting cannot work. Anyone can fix this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ClLG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ezdu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in many cases that if the mailer is owner checked then you need to make sure that the email you put in "Email address to send mail from" is the same as the user who owns the contact.

I am not sure about your SMTP but for SES it is very common. Also ensure when you create email, in the advance settings the from address is blank or have the same email address.

Comment: I have figured out my Mail Box don't support either the Return_path overtwritenn or Webhook. That's the reason. I have to switch other like Gmail or SES.